# Sitecore: Follow relational links in Sitecore Query

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have an item structure that doens't correspond to "documents" in the standard Sitecore sense. It corresponds to data items.

One of the relationships that my items have is the following:

```
Person -> State -> Country
```

Where a Person has a link field to a State and state's have link fields to a Country.

My question is: How would one write a query to retrieve all of the People who have an eventual link to a Country of a certain abbreviation?

I'm stumped as to how to do it in Sitecore Query. My current solution is using LINQ and several queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the links between these items where created using a Reference field, such as a Droplink, Treelist, Droptree, etc., you can traverse the references/referrers using the Sitecore Links database.

Here is an example (untested) that starts with a country item and fetches any referring states. The same query is performed on the states to fetch any referring people. The results are added to a generic `List<Item>` collection.

```
List<Item> peopleList = new List<Item>();

var countryReferences = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferences(countryItem);
var referringStates = countryReferences.Select(c => c.GetTargetItem()).Where(c => c.Template.Key == "state");
foreach (var state in referringStates)
{
    var stateReferences = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferences(state);
    var referringPeople = stateReferences.Select(s => s.GetTargetItem()).Where(s => s.Template.Key == "person");
    foreach (var person in referringPeople)
    {
        peopleList.Add(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know about the Links database. That makes my life so much easier.

Comment: The followup to this is, can this structure be leveraged in Sitecore's query language?

Comment: The `Globals.LinkDatabase` is the only access point to the links database that I am aware of. Is there a specific reason you are limited to using Sitecore Query?

Comment: No, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something that would make Sitecore Query more powerful than plain XPath

Comment: Another thank you for this post. As it turns out, even our senior Sitecore dev didn't know about the Links database.